# Most efficient way to roll each column in a numpy array by x steps

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have a 2D array that holds data as shown in the picture below. 
Each column needs to be rolled up the same number of steps as the index of the column. How could I do this most ideally? I am thinking about a for loop where I iterate over the columns, rolling them up by i and then applying the column of the array to this rolled result.

Is there a more efficient way?

[image]

Comment: Do I need to understand why this is being downvoted? If there is something wrong with the way I asked the question, I'll update it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use reshape like so:

```
>>> a = np.r_[np.tril(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 10))), np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 10))]
>>> a
array([[7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 2, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [6, 1, 3, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 4, 1, 2, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 9, 7, 3, 7, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 4, 2, 9, 1, 6, 8, 8, 0, 0],
       [8, 5, 4, 5, 2, 6, 5, 5, 8, 0],
       [9, 3, 4, 6, 1, 4, 8, 3, 9, 1],
       [3, 7, 7, 7, 3, 7, 9, 8, 2, 1],
       [8, 1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4, 8, 7, 8],
       [5, 8, 4, 6, 1, 1, 9, 7, 5, 6],
       [7, 3, 9, 9, 1, 1, 3, 4, 8, 1],
       [4, 7, 7, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 2, 7]])
>>> 
>>> m, n = a.shape
>>> buffer = np.zeros((m+1, n), dtype=a.dtype, order='F')
>>> buffer.ravel(order='F')[:m*n].reshape(m, n, order='F')[...] = a
>>> result = buffer[:-1]
>>> result
array([[7, 4, 6, 2, 5, 8, 4, 8, 8, 1],
       [9, 3, 8, 6, 9, 7, 8, 5, 9, 1],
       [5, 2, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8],
       [7, 1, 1, 3, 1, 6, 8, 8, 7, 6],
       [6, 4, 7, 9, 2, 4, 9, 8, 5, 1],
       [7, 9, 2, 5, 1, 7, 4, 7, 8, 7],
       [2, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 9, 4, 2, 0],
       [2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 1, 3, 8, 0, 0],
       [8, 3, 7, 6, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 7, 2, 6, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 1, 4, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 8, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: @unutbu High praise, indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is probably the optimal way to do this. I found a more elegant way to write it, but unfortunately the realloc could incur another copy..  `b = a.copy('F'); b.resize(m+1, n); result = b[:-1]`